# Magento- Disable PayPal Express checkout?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have PayPal Merchant Payments Pro set up which allows me to accepts Credit Cards, but in addition to that the store automatically accepts PayPal Express Checkout ?

Any way to **disable** PayPal Express Checkout as one of the payment options, Keeping PayPal Payments Pro active?

Comment: You should see the options for enabling/disabling paypal services under System->Configuration-> Payment Methods (tab)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about Magento Administration. Questions like this can be asked on [Magento.SE](//magento.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score -2):

## Store View > Main Website

Sales >> Payment Methods >> PayPal Payment Gateways(Payflow from PayPal) >> Payflow Link >> Required Payday Settings >>  Enable Express Checkout

Select *No*

Comment: this one is for Magento2